# Unable to map polygon over points and point density

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

This toy example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

# create random points
p <- runif(50, 0, 11) %>% cbind(runif(50, 0, 11)) %>% st_multipoint %>% st_sfc %>% st_cast("POINT") %>% st_sf
# append coordinates for ggplot
p <- cbind(p, st_coordinates(p))

# plot points, point density
ggplot(p, aes(x=X, y=Y)) + geom_point() + 
  stat_density2d(geom="tile", aes(fill=..density..), contour=F, alpha=.5, data=p)
```

...returns:
[image]
Trying to add a polygon:

```
# create polygon
s <- rbind(c(1, 1), c(10, 1), c(10, 10), c(1, 10), c(1, 1)) %>% list %>% st_polygon %>% st_sfc %>% st_sf

# plot points, point density and polygon
ggplot(p, aes(x=X, y=Y)) + geom_point() + 
  stat_density2d(geom="tile", aes(fill=..density..), contour=F, alpha=.5, data=p) + 
  geom_sf(data=s, fill=NA)
```

...returns:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'X' not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the `geom_sf` layer inherits the global aes `x` and `y`. However in `s` there are no vars `X` and `Y`. To prevent this simply set `inherit.aes = FALSE` in your call to `geom_sf`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# create random points
p <- runif(50, 0, 11) %>% cbind(runif(50, 0, 11)) %>% st_multipoint %>% st_sfc %>% st_cast("POINT") %>% st_sf
# append coordinates for ggplot
p <- cbind(p, st_coordinates(p))
# create polygon
s <- rbind(c(1, 1), c(10, 1), c(10, 10), c(1, 10), c(1, 1)) %>% 
  list %>% 
  st_polygon %>% 
  st_sfc %>% 
  st_sf

# plot points, point density and polygon
ggplot(p, aes(x=X, y=Y)) + geom_point() + 
  stat_density2d(geom="tile", aes(fill=..density..), contour=F, alpha=.5, data=p) + 
  geom_sf(data=s, fill=NA, inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image]